# how to limit the first dex size while building android app by using multi-dex

Tags: android, dex, android-multidex, dexopt

First，I face this problem：

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed:Unable toexecute dex:
method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

so，I try to division the dex provided by Google.refer Building Apps with Over 65K Methods

And I unPack the apk,it really  contains two dex file and the first dex still too large,cause the apk cannot be installed in android 2.3 by cmd.

```
log:Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]
android 2.3 linearalloc about 5M.
```

How to do it so that the app can install in android 2.3.

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27766126/1233652

Answer (score 0):

This is the limitation. You cannot run mutidex app on device with api older than 14. The full list of limitaions is [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#limitations).

Comment: This is not true. You **can** run multidex app on pre-4.0 Android, though you have to thoroughly test it (this is also what the linked documentation says).