# How to restrict method counts in primary dex in andorid application

Tags: android, android-build, android-multidex

I want to build a multidex android application. But my limitation is, I want to keep the method counts in the primary dex less than some value (e.g. 45k or 50k) instead of the 64k limit. So whenever the application will be built, my primary dex will have the above restricted no of methods and rest of the things will go to the other dex.

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: In pre-1.5 gradle plugin you could add [additional dex parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27766126/1233652), but with latest versions you [can't access dex task](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/adt-dev/uGogKKuuHi8).

Comment: @Alex thanks a lot. It helped.